Why Is OpenBSD History Not Persistent?
I installed OpenBSD and quickly realised that the history is not persistent. I'm guessing this is a security related feature. But I don't know why this is a good idea. Anyone?

command line history is a shell feature.  What shell are you using?  is HISTFILE set?

The default shell - ksh.

Security related features are always a good idea.

@Vilinkameni yes, but how does this improve security?

Keeping history in a file would also keep potential sensitive information, such as passwords in the history file. This is just one example. Of course, one could avoid entering sensitive information on the command line, but every measure to decrease the possibility of security holes helps.

@Vilinkameni That makes sense thanks.

If ksh is your shell, the following must all be true for history to persist across shell instances:

HISTSIZE must be non-zero or it won't even remember history within the current shell.  Default is 512, I usually set this much higher.
HISTFILE must be a filename to load and save history in.  This file must be writable (only?) to the current user.

Likely the above is not ksh specific, but POSIX shell specific.  Other shells use the above and also have additional history variables to further fine tune history behavior.

See also https://man.openbsd.org/ksh#HISTFILE  for both HISTFILE behaviour and the default HISTSIZE value of the OpenBSD ksh shell.

Looks like both the default and the behavior have changed between versions of ksh, I probably looked at an older man page.  Thanks for the better link.

POSIX manual page for sh(1p) contains the description of HISTFILE and HISTSIZE variables, so they are part of the standard. HISTFILE is marked as "UP" (="User Portability Utilities"), which means it is optional.

Reading multiple man pages, the two variables are required for POSIX but the behavior can vary quite a bit as long as the minimum is implemented.
